# UserServicePresence Object : Not able to access UserId field in formula?

Tags: reporting, formula-field, servicecloud, omnichannel

**REQUIREMENTS :**
I need to create a field on UserServicePresence object, to check if the current user is the user referenced in UserServicePresence records.

I need this field to be used in reports, to dynamically display records according to the current connected user.

**WHAT I DID TRY :**
I try to create a checkbox formula field on UserServicePresence object, the logic was simple :
CASESAFEID(UserId) = CASESAFEID($User.Id)

**ERROR :**
The UserServicePresence.UserId field is not accessible through formula field.

[image]

--> Do you have any workaround ?

Thanks :)